# If-else statement giving error

Tags: .net

normal if else statement is working but optimized if else not working

[image]

calVal == "0" ? "1" : employee.TotalLeaveDays.TotalCorrectValue.ToString();

Comment: That's a ternary expression giving you an error, not an if-statement.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the value. It's as if you just had `"1";` as a line in your source code.

Comment: So, what does your statement do? If `calVal` equal to "0", then "1" else `employee.TotalLeaveDays.TotalCorrectValue.ToString()`, then what?! A value returned by ternary operator must be assigned or used somehow. It just like if you write `1 + 1;`...It is 2, so what, how to interpret this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to assign calVal? If yes, try:

```
calVal = ((calVal == "0") ? "1" : employee.TotalLeaveDays.TotalCorrectValue.ToString());
```

The shorthand if statement if correct, but the compiler complains that you aren't doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

calVal = ( expression to evaluate ) ? output if true : output if false

I'm not sure what you are trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

```
calVal == "0" ? "1" : employee.TotalLeaveDays.TotalCorrectValue.ToString();
```

statement will return true or false so must assign to any variable or kept this statement in `if` condition.